# Cross-posting questions and answers on other online forums

Tags: discussion, sources-and-citations, answers

Recently, I joined a online forum (not a Q&A site) and I've started posting some questions there that I also post here on Hinduism.SE.

If I get a really good answer on the other website, I thought it's better to copy-paste the same answer here as well to share knowledge.

1. Is such cross-posting of questions and answers allowed? (Any copyright rules to be aware?)
2. If yes, is it better to post good answers (from other forums) as a [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) or a normal answer?
3. Also, on Hinduism.SE, is a [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) held to the same quality-standards as that of a normal answer?

FYI, [one of the top-voted answers](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/112/2995) on our site is a Wiki. It's missing 1 or 2 references.

Comment: [How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94022/260388) and [What do I do when I have a good, off site resource which answers somebody’s question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211578/260388) may help.